# I'm bringing money from Kuwait to Australia via the Philippines

Tags: customs-and-immigration, money, australia, philippines

I will be staying one night in the Philippines then return to Australia.
Will I have any trouble bringing $10,000.00 dollars Australian back through these countries

Answer (score 2):

You're allowed to bring as much cash as you like, but [you must declare amounts of A$10,000 or more when travelling to or from Australia.](http://www.austrac.gov.au/travellers/declare-your-cash-you-travel)

In the Philippines, [the equivalent limit is US$10,000](https://rapidvisa.com/bringing-cash-philippines/), so even declaration is not necessary (as long as USD>AUD).